# What should I do to convert a encrypted NSData to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsdata

```
NSData *jsonDataEncrypted = [jsonStringEncrypted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDicEncrypted = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDataEncrypted options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

The code above is'n work. The

> jsonDicEncrypted

is null.

Comment: Use the `error` parameter to figure out the kind of the error

Comment: sorry, I forgot that

Comment: the error is "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set". What should I do next? The NSData has been encrypted.

Comment: The `NSJSONSerialization` API accepts only the data representation of plain clear text. You need to decrypt the data.

Comment: But I have to encrypt it and send it to backend

Comment: If you have to send encrypted text `NSJSONSerialization` is not the right API. Use for example base64 encoding to serialize the data.

Comment: @OttoYing you need to supply more information, add sample data to the question. Also there is no encryption in the question code, only Base64 encoding, Base64 is not encryption.

Answer (score -1):

```
   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:&err];
  NSDictionary *jsons=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

use this code

Answer (score -1):

Check this.

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *connectionError) {
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //UI update here
             });
          }];
```